# ORM: Sequelize: How can I return except some json data?

Tags: json, sequelize.js

This question is about the sequelize query. Queries three tables with many-to-many relationships. The following query:

```js
const data = await product.findOne ({
   where: { product_id: id },
   include: [
     {
       model: category
     }
   ]
});
```

It returns the following json data:

```
"category": {
        "product_id": 1,
        "name": "Arc d'Triomphe",
        "description": "This beautiful and iconic T-shirt will no doubt lead you to your own triumph.",
        "price": "14.99",
        "discounted_price": "0.00",
        "image": "arc-d-triomphe.gif",
        "image_2": "arc-d-triomphe-2.gif",
        "thumbnail": "arc-d-triomphe-thumbnail.gif",
        "display": 0,
        "categories": [
            {
                "category_id": 1,
                "name": "French",
                "description": "The French have always had an eye for beauty. One look at the T-shirts below and you'll see that same appreciation has been applied abundantly to their postage stamps. Below are some of our most beautiful and colorful T-shirts, so browse away! And don't forget to go all the way to the bottom - you don't want to miss any of them!",
                "department_id": 1,
                "product_category": {
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "category_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to make the above json data as below. How do I query?

```
"category": [
        {
            "category_id": 1,
            "name": "French",
            "department_id": 1
        }
    ]
```

If you need a model file, can you give me a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries as shown below:

```js
const query = await product.findOne({
   where: { product_id: id },
   include: {
     model: category,
     attributes: ['category_id', 'name', 'department_id'],
     through: { attributes: [] }
   },
   attributes: []
});
```

The following json data is displayed:

```
 "category": {
     "categories": [
         {
             "category_id": 1,
             "name": "French",
             "department_id": 1
         }
     ]
 }
```

The key point is `through: { attributes: [] }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find **attributes** at this [document](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#attributes). We have a simple code like that:

```
const data = await product.findOne ({
   where: {product_id: id},
   include: [
     {
       model: category,
       attributes: ['category_id', 'name', 'department_id']
     }
   ]
});
```

Comment: As mentioned above, the last property 'product_category` is returned even if you query according to your answer because it is three tables made up of many-tomany relationship.

Comment: Do you try exclude in attributes?

Comment: Yes, i did. Note that `product_category` is a table that acts as a bridge.